# Elasticsearch - searching with "keyword" type don't work

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I use Elasticsearch Java rest client 6.1. When I try to find logs due to a few parametrs than can be in one field I get nothing.

Here is my code:

```
 @Override
    public SearchResponse findLogsByValues(ElasticSearchLogRequest esLogRequest, Pageable pageable) {
        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("portal-logs-*");

        SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        BoolQueryBuilder bqb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
 if (esLogRequest.getLevels() != null) {
            Iterator<String> iterator = esLogRequest.getLevels().iterator();
            int counter = 0;
            SpanOrQueryBuilder spanOrQueryBuilder = null;
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                if (counter == 0) {
                    spanOrQueryBuilder = new SpanOrQueryBuilder(QueryBuilders.
                            spanTermQuery("level", iterator.next().toLowerCase()));
                } else {
                    spanOrQueryBuilder.addClause(QueryBuilders.
                            spanTermQuery("level", iterator.next().toLowerCase()));
                }
                counter++;
            }
            bqb.filter(spanOrQueryBuilder);
        }
 try {
            searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return searchResponse;
    }
```

Here is my json request:

```
{

    "levels": ["TRACE","INFO"]

}
```

Here is how log(object) looks like in ES:

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "error": "",
    "message": "",
    "data": {
        "content": [
                    {
                    "level": "INFO",
                    "module": "test module",
                    "ip": "192.168.3.93",
                    "thread": "test thread",
                    "sessionId": "1",
                    "office": "1",
                    "message": "test message 3",
                    "userName": "user",
                    "timeStamp": "2018-01-25T08:02:50.000Z",
                    "userLogin": "user",
                    "node": "first node",
                    "system": "super system 1",
                    "port": 9300,
                    "header": "test Header",
                    "submodule": "test submodule",
                    "location": {
                        "lon": -71.34,
                        "lat": 41.12
                    },
                    "operation": "some operation",
                    "device": "some device"
        }
        ],
        "totalPages": 1,
        "last": true,
        "totalElements": 0,
        "size": 0,
        "number": 0,
        "sort": null,
        "first": true,
        "numberOfElements": 0
    }
}
```

Here is my mapping template:

```
  PUT _template/portal-logs
{
  "template": "portal-logs-*",
  "settings": { "number_of_shards": 5 },
  "mappings": {
      "logs_info": {
        "_all": {
          "enabled": false
        },
        "properties": {
          "device": {"type": "keyword"},
          "header": {"type": "text"},
          "ip": {"type": "keyword"},
          "level": {"type": "keyword"},
          "location": {"type": "geo_point"},
          "message": {"type": "text"},
          "module": {"type": "keyword"},
          "node": {"type": "keyword"},
          "office": {"type": "keyword"},
          "operation": {"type": "keyword"},
          "port": {"type": "integer"},
          "sessionId": {"type": "keyword"},
          "submodule": {"type": "keyword"},
          "system": {"type": "keyword"},
          "thread": {"type": "keyword"},
          "timeStamp": {"type": "date"},
          "userLogin": {"type": "keyword"},
          "userName": {"type": "keyword"}
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

So when in mapping field "level" and set it as "text" - it works fine but when I set "keyword" - I receive an empty json. 
I need that field "level" has a strict type "keyword" and it has to work when I want to get all logs that have "level" "INFO" or "TRACE". 
What should I do in such case? Why with keyword it's not working?

Comment: If you remove `.toLowerCase()` it should work right? Since you're searching for `INFO` not `info`. Also use a `TermQuery` instead of a `SpanTermQuery`.

Comment: When I remove .toLowerCase() it's not working also. How I can constract TermQuery when I want to use searching for one value or another (it can be more than 2 value of searching).

Comment: Did you try the suggestion by @Val to use a `TermQuery`?  My suggestion is to write and test your queries before you code them.  I use SoapUI but anything that lets you send http requests will do (e.g. curl or a browser plugin).  Only after the query works do I translate it into code.

Comment: No, I haven't try to use TermQuery in such case because I don't know how to use it "OR" condition when it requires only for one field. May you give a hint or example?

Comment: for example in some object in "level" field can be "INFO" or "TRACE". And I need to fiend all object with "INFO" or "TRACE"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the `keyword` type, your field won't be analysed and will require an exact match for your search terms, including case sensitivity. If you set the field type to `text`, it will be analysed, which under the default analyzer, will make the search case insensitive.

In addition, unless your level field contains more than one term, you should be able to use a TermsQuery to search multiple values. For example (in DSL format):

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "level": [ "INFO", "TRACE" ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: my field "level" can have only one value - "INFO" or "TRACE". But in search request(or query) I want to use few meanings of "level" for finding all objects with field "level" that will have "TRACE" or "INFO". So, in my case I use request of "levels" (that is a set) for finding all objects which have "level" "INFO" or "TRACE".

Comment: so, you query is right but not "level" but "levels". And I added how object(log) looks like.

Comment: In your schema, the field is called "level", so that is what you would query on. The terms query above will find all results where level=INFO or TRACE.

Comment: this helps  bqb.filter(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("level", esLogRequest.getLevels()));